# Dataframe as class attribute, how to select portions of it with pandas in class function?

Tags: class, pandas, attributes, dataframe, slice

I have something similar to that

```
class Cheese(object):
    def __init__(self,df):
       self.df = df ##df is a pd.DataFrame
```

And I want to select portions of self.df basically (a function in the class) in a function let's say:

```
def cheese_selection(self, cheez):
     dftemp = self.df[self.df['Fromage'] == cheez]
     return dftemp
```

Cheese or no cheese I am looking for an answer for this specific question and not an alternative :D - the program tells me something like the class doedn't have a **getitem** but I tried to override it and it somehow failed to give me non empty dataframe (does it make any sense to declare the key in def **getitem**(self, key) as self.df['Fromage'] == cheez, I don't think so. all getitem with underscores before and after of course) 
Would you have an explanation and a solution for me ? I guess the problem is with a dataframe - maybe it would work with a numpy but I really am looking for this specific answer :D Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking -  the function you posted works - what specific error are you seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works fine:

```
class Cheese(object):
    def __init__(self,df):
       self.df = df ##df is a pd.DataFrame
    def cheese_selection(self, cheez):
         dftemp = self.df[self.df['Fromage'] == cheez]
         return dftemp
```

when passed a DataFrame:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([["Cheddar"], ["Stilton"]], columns=["Fromage"])

In [12]: c = Cheese(df)

In [13]: c.cheese_selection("Stilton")
Out[13]:
   Fromage
1  Stilton
```

---

To use `__getitem__` etc. you have to [subclass DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures).

Comment: Ok and so I suppose it also works for 2 different keys and an & ... I don't get it - it is still sending me the error the class blahblah has no getitem ...

Comment: @zazoupile how are you calling this? i think you must be doing c["Stilton"] or similar. ?